# DragStarted and DragCompleted events for Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows

Please are there any event handlers that handle the drag started and drag completed events for sliders in windows 8 apps? Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ManipulationCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted(v=vs.105).aspx) and [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted(v=vs.105).aspx) Events for achieving the same. 
Read more on [`How to handle manipulation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff426933(v=vs.105).aspx)